# Submitting POST XML query from Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, post

I'm trying to figure out how to do an OGC CSW (Catalog Service for the Web) simple POST operation using a blob of XML in Matlab. I've been reading the documentation for Mathworks `urlread` and the 3rd party `urlread2`, and I'm trying to replicate this simple example:

```
wget http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geoportal/csw --post-file=./post_query.xml
```

where `post_query.xml` is:

```
<csw:GetRecords xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" version="2.0.2" service="CSW" resultType="results" startPosition="1" maxRecords="11" outputSchema="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"> <csw:Query typeNames="csw:Record" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" >
<csw:ElementSetName>full</csw:ElementSetName>
<csw:Constraint version="1.1.0">
  <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
      <ogc:PropertyName>apiso:modified</ogc:PropertyName> <ogc:Literal>2014-09-30</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
      <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
      <ogc:PropertyName>apiso:modified</ogc:PropertyName> <ogc:Literal>2014-10-02</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:Filter>
</csw:Constraint>
</csw:Query>
</csw:GetRecords>
```

I've tried a lot of things, but the only thing I've been able to get to work is `urlread2` like this:

```
url = 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geoportal/csw'
paramString=fileread('post_query.xml')
header.name='Content-Type';
header.value='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
[output,extras] = urlread2(url,'POST',paramString,header);
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Is there a way to do this using `urlread` or some other tool in the standard Matlab distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found that I don't need that header stuff, so this simpler version also works:

```
url = 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geoportal/csw';
paramString=fileread('post_query.xml');
[output,extras] = urlread2(url,'POST',paramString);
```

I guess that's getting pretty simple, actually!